# Restriction of the Steinberg representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ the group $GL(n,F)$ where F is a locally compact non Archimedean field, and $G^{0}$ the subgroup of $G$ consists of elements $g$ in $G$ such that $\det(g)$ in $\mathcal{O}_{F}^{\times}$, where $\mathcal{O}_{F}$ is the ring of integers of $F$.

We denote $St$ the Steinberg representation of $G$. We know that $St$ is an irreducible representation.
My question : It's true that the restriction of $St$ to $G^{0}$ is also irreducible ?

Comment: Another question : Is the representation $St$ have level zero, that is $St$ have fixed vectors under any pro-unipotent radical of a maximal parahorique subgroup of $G$ ?

Comment: it remains irreducible even if you restrict to SL(N).

Comment: St is a quotient of $Ind_B^G 1$, which is generated by Iwahori invariant. Then St is also generated by Iwahori invariant.